# How do I change the text color of a default UserCreationForm in Django?

Tags: python, django, twitter-bootstrap

I'm working on a simple website using django and bootstrap.
I've used the UserCreationForm class to make a standards registration page.
But I'd like to make the texts a little darker so it's more legible and has a good contrast from the background image and mask. What'd be the best solution?

[image]

View module

```
def register(request):
    #if the request method is a  'get'
    #Yes initial data
    if request.method != 'POST':
        form = UserCreationForm()
    #no initial data
    #f the request method is a 'post'
    else:
        form = UserCreationForm(data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            new_user=form.save()
            authenticated_user = authenticate(username=new_user.username,
                                          password=request.POST['password1'])
            login(request, aunthenticated_user)
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('my_websites:home'))
    context = {'form': form}
    return render(request, 'users/register.html', context)
```

bootstrap

```
{% extends "pages/base.html" %}
{% load bootstrap5 %}

{% block header %}
<div="container my-5">
  <div class="bg-image position-relative rounded" style="background:url('https://wallpaperaccess.com/full/1708426.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed; -webkit-background-size: cover; -moz-background-size: cover; -o-background-size: cover; background-size: cover;  height: 100vh;">
    <div class="mask position-absolute rounded p-4 top-0 end-0 bottom-0 start-0" style="background-color: rgba(251, 251, 251, 0.8);">
      <h2 class="text-center display-6"> Register </h2>
      <form method="post" action="{% url 'users:register' %}" class="form text-dark" style="max-width: 400px; margin:0 auto;">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {% bootstrap_form form %}
        {% buttons %}
           <button name="submit" class="btn btn-dark">Register 
</button>
        {% endbuttons %}
        <input type="hidden" name="next" value="{% url 'my_websites:home' %}" />
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

thank you for your time.

Comment: Your final page is just plain HTML (look at the source in your browser), so you can just add your own CSS styling. Add a css import in your header and specify your own default text color.

Comment: I tried that adding a simple 'text-danger' class to my form but it doesn't change the color of the small texts bellow text areas. Am I missing something?

Comment: use your browser developer tools to see which css is applied to each element in your page. that's the only way to understand which selector takes precedence. Probably the text elements inside the form each have their own classes which take precedence over the enclosing element (the `<form>` element)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're using Bootstrap, which pre-defined a set of CSS classes you can use for colors.

Try changing your `<h2 class="text-center display-6"> Register </h2>` tag to `<h2 class="text-center display-6 text-danger"> Register </h2>` - it will likely turn red.

The `bootstrap_form` tag allows you to pass parameters to control the CSS class attributes applied.

For example, try:

`{% bootstrap_form form field_class="text-danger" %}`

For available parameters you can pass, see the documentation: https://django-bootstrap-v5.readthedocs.io/en/latest/templatetags.html#bootstrap-field

For more information on how to use colors with Bootstrap, including defining your own color theme to use, see here: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/utilities/colors/ Good luck!

Comment: May I ask how can I possibly change the color of the texts that are bellow text areas? I added a 'text-danger' class to the form and it does change the color of texts above text areas but not of the ones that are below them.

Comment: I'll amend my answer with more information.